# Gulp having issues with folders that are named like a file

Tags: gulp, bower, animate.css

I have a gulp task:

```
gulp.task('css-dependencies', function() {
  return gulp.src(['bower_components/**/*.css','!bower_components/**/*.min.css'])
        .pipe(rename({dirname: './css'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

which works fine for all other components, however I want to use `animate.css` and adding via bower puts it in a folder called `animate.css`:

```
Project
 |    
 +-- bower_components
    |  
    +-- animate.css
        |
        +--animate.css
        +--animate.min.css (etc)
```

which causes gulp fail on the rename task:

> Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open ‘~/css/animate.css' at Error (native)

Other than putting a specific exemption in, how can I fix this?

Comment: You  need to  paste the code you have tried not just the code works fine.

Comment: @catssay That code I have doesn't work for the case I've described. I can put in a specific use case for it and that would work but it's not scaleable. As src is a pattern match (I believe) I can't think of a way to only matches files, not directories.

Comment: I have looked for the source code of gulp and traced the interpreter of path, it's a module called [glob-parent](https://github.com/es128/glob-parent), the `bower_components/**/*.css` would give you a parent path of `bower_components` not bower_components/*`, so it in fact return all css files in `bower_components` not in `bower_components/*`, if you want exactly files in `bower_components/*`, you need to escape the `*` like this `bower_components/\\*/*.css`.You can raise aa issuse in gulp project.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, I think what you're saying is it would only give me the css that exists at the parent level and nothing in the deeper folder structure?

Comment: `gulp.src()` has no problem with folders that are named like files and will happily go into the `animate.css` folder and select all the `.css` files there. You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: @Sven Schoenung Yes, `gulp.src()` has no problem with that situation, I am sorry for answering without verification. @Rudiger in fact `gulp.src(['path'], options)` is also accepted, available options can be seen [here](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob). `**` is supported by default, I don't know whether there are anything with your problem.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung I'm not sure if the MCV is in reference to my question. If it is I do believe this has met it. I've updated the question explaining it differently.

Comment: From the MVCE page: "Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!". The example in your question **DOESN'T** reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung I've put the original 'do stuff' code back in which produces the problem however the issue is with the src pattern match because no matter what is inside the task, the directory patten of `bower_components/animate.css` is matched as so won't go any deeper into the folder structure, which is the issue at hand, which is why I removed the contents in the first place.

Comment: Your updated code still doesn't reproduce the problem as you describe it. Instead the task fails with `Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory`

Comment: The sass doesn't cause the issue as you suspected, it's the rename and as it doesn't seem to crash gulp in a way I'd expect I missed it in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the pattern in `gulp.src()` matches two things:

1. The directory `bower_component/animate.css`
2. The file `bower_component/animate.css/animate.css`

You then proceed to do a `rename({dirname: './css'})` which means you end up with:

1. A directory `css/animate.css`
2. A file `css/animate.css`

Both cannot exist at the same time obviously.

You need to make sure that your pattern in `gulp.src()` doesn't match any of the directories themselves (only files in those directories).

`gulp.src()` uses [`glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) internally and options to `gulp.src()` are passed through to `glob`. That means you can use the [`nodir` option](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#options) of `glob` to prevent directories from being matched:

```
return gulp.src(['bower_components/**/*.css','!bower_components/**/*.min.css'], {nodir:true})
  .pipe(rename({dirname: './css'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```